# is EDMessage.framework thread safe?

Tags: cocoa, email, thread-safety

Hey, I didn't see this anywhere in their FAQ and wanted to know if EDMessage.framework [ http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/EDFrameworks/ ] is thread safe.  If it matters, I'd be sending out bulk quantities of html emails.  I am currently sending each email one at a time on a non-main thread.  Also, from the looks of the info on it its pretty old (by SO standards), so if anyone has a better framework in mind (that is thread safe) please tell.  I am currently sending each email one at a time on a non-main thread.